# "Checked" attribute not working after reloading page

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

I have some HTML code that I am using for a website that looks like this: (with some changed variables)

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="YES">
    YES 
    </label>
</div>
    <div class="radio">
    <label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO" checked="checked">
    NO
    </label>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine and "No" is automatically checked when I first load the page, but when I check yes and then reload again, the "yes" option is automatically checked rather than the "no" one. This is a problem because upon checking yes, I display more information and the default should be "no" and display no extra information. 
I have tried:

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO" checked="checked">
```

and

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO" checked="true">
```

and

```
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO" checked>
```

and

```
<input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="YES" checked="false">    
<input type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO" checked="true">
```

but whenever I check yes, the next time I load the page "yes" is checked again. I am using firefox, and using private browsing does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use js, here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dp2yxnyc/2/)

HTML:

```
<form>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="yes" type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="YES" checked="checked">
            YES 
            </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input id="no" type="radio" name="radio2" class="radio2" value="NO">
            NO
            </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#no').prop('checked', 'checked');
});
```